# Traceback Errors in Python

Tags: visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, anaconda

Started coding a python program using BeautifulSoup to track GTA V price on Amazon.
Getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 68, in <module>
    check_price()
  File "scraper.py", line 35, in check_price
    send_mail()
  File "scraper.py", line 50, in send_mail
    server.login('sathwikapps@gmail.com', 'Jaybeatx')
  File "D:\Users\sathw\anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 697, in login
    "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

My github repository is : https://github.com/SathwikChiluveru/GTA-V-Price-Tracker

Comment: If `'Jaybeatx' `is your actual pw, you need to change it ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Try to activate on you gmail smtp access for thirdparty :)